# Does Bluemix local has Docker containers support?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've read Bluemix local documentation https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#local.
It's not clear if Bluemix Local supports Docker containers or not.

-thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Local does not support Docker containers at this time. For questions like this about Bluemix platform capabilities, the best place is [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html). Stack Overflow is intended for technical programming questions.